# Simple node copying from XML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
        xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/POSLog.xsd">
<dtv:PosTransactionProperties>
<dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode><![CDATA[RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS]]></dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode>
<dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue><![CDATA[qwerty@yahoo.com]]></dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue>
</dtv:PosTransactionProperties>
</POSLog>
```

And the following XSLT  code, which now copies only data from the specific selected elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                 xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
                 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        >

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="//POSLog">
<POSLog>
                <xsl:for-each select = "../dtv:PosTransactionProperties[dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode='RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS']/dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue[string-length() &gt; 0]" >
                <xsl:copy-of select = "." />
            </xsl:for-each>
</POSLog>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, based on my requirement, I need to copy to the output XML entire node "dtv:PosTransactionProperties", could you, please, advice how to do this copying.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs dtv"
version="2.0">  

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="POSLog" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dtv:PosTransactionProperties[dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode='RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS']/dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue[string-length() &gt; 0]"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dtv:PosTransactionProperties[dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode='RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS']/dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue[string-length() &gt; 0]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Markup_Fanatic,

Thank you for your help, your code produced the following:

---

```
<POSLog>
   <dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
                                    xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
                                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">qwerty@yahoo.com</dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue>
</POSLog>
```

---

But it is not exactly what I need, I was able do modify it:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs dtv"
version="2.0">  

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="dtv:PosTransactionProperties[dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode='RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS']/dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue[string-length() &gt; 0]">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".."/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

and it produced the following:

---

```
RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS
<dtv:PosTransactionProperties xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
                              xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode>RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS</dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode>
   <dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue>qwerty@yahoo.com</dtv:PosTransactionPropertyValue>
</dtv:PosTransactionProperties>
```

---

which is very close to the target, only one question, how to get rid of the "RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS" on top, which is a value of the element

```
<dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode>RECEIPT_EMAIL_ADDRESS</dtv:PosTransactionPropertyCode>.
```

Comment: could you try to explain your answer and how (where exactly) it solves the question?